# Making the objectContext.CommandTimeout configurable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to make the CommandTimeout value more configurable.  I'm wondering if this is best practice to do so?

I add the following to my `<appsettings>` node in my Web.config file:

```
<add key="commandTimeValue" value ="60"/>
```

The I added the following to the top of my controllers under the :

```
using (var db = new myDAL())...

Int32 timeoutVal = Convert.ToInt32

(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["commandTimeValue"]);
((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = timeoutVal;
```

Is this the right way to do this?  What are some other alternatives?

Answer (score 5):

I do not like the name `myDAL` as a class name.  It is very cryptic and does not follow C# naming conventions.  I would prefer `DataAccessLayer` or `<entity>DataAccessLayer` where `<entity>` is the name of the class the DAL is for.

That being said, why don't you inject the timeout value into your DAL class.  The constructor could be something like

```
public void myDAL(int timeout)
{
    if (timeout > 0)
    {
         ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = timeout;
    }

    // other constructor commands
}
```